# How does this reverse list function work in Dr. Racket?

Tags: racket

I am using Dr. Racket - Advanced Student Lanaguage. I was looking to make a function that reverses a list. I know there is already the reverse function in Dr. Racket, but I am trying to understand things and work it out. Anyways, I can't understand how this function actually works. From what I understand is that it takes the first element in a list and appends it. I don't understand to what list it is appended to, and how does appending the first letter of the list work? To me it seems like it would just create the same list ("a" "b" "c" "d"). I am assuming that append means attaching an element to the end of a list.
(list "a")
(list "a" "b")
(list "a" "b" "c")
(list "a" "b" "c" "d")

Again, my questions are:

1. What list is the reversed list appended to? (e.x. LOL or lst?)
2. How is it actually reversing the list?

- I first learned python, so that may be an issue with me understanding this.

```
(define LOL (list "a" "b" "c" "d"))


(check-expect (reverse-list empty) empty)
(check-expect (reverse-list LOL) (list "d" "c" "b" "a")) 

(define (reverse-list lst)
  (if (null? lst) empty
      (append (reverse-list (cdr lst)) (list (car lst)))))
```

I tried playing with the debug function, but can't seem to understand how it works.

Comment: The first element of the list is appended to a list created by recursively calling `reverse-list` on the rest of the list.

Comment: Good idea to get familiar with [the reference](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/index.html) to find documentation on functions you're not familiar with like [`append`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._append%29%29)

Comment: I looked at the reference before, but it doesn't explain how append is able to reverse the list. It is taking the first element of LOL which is "a" and placing it at the end of the list created by append. With that logical it would just output the same (list "a" "b" "c" "d"), but it doesn't. It outputs (list "d" "c" "b" "a").

Comment: I found the answer. I had to switch DrRacket language to intermediate so that I could use stepper. Basically append combined with the recursion creates a stack of lists after removing the 1st letter in the list and repeats with what is left over. e.x. (list "a" "b" "c" "d") at the bottom and (list "d") at the top. Once LOL is null, an empty list is created. The stack is then unstacked and appends the first letter of each list to the empty list.

Comment: Use the stepper! Click the "Step" icon in DrRacket. Then click the forward icon repeatedly to see how the computation unfolds.

Answer (score 1):

The puzzling part of the code is:

```
(append (reverse-list (cdr lst))
        (list (car lst)))
```

You are appending two lists:

- `(reverse-list (cdr lst))`
- `(list (car lst))`

Let's assume that `reverse-list` works and actually reverses a list. So we rely on the fact that `reverse-list` takes a list, and reverse it.

If your input list is `(1 2 3)`, then `(cdr list)` is `(2 3)`, and `(reverse-list (cdr list))` is `(3 2)`.

The second term for `append` is a list constructor `(list (car list))`, which in our example would be `(list 1)`, which evaluates to a list of a single element `(1)`.

You can now append them together, which gives `(3 2 1)`, which is indeed the reverse of your initial list.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the simplest lists. Try it like this:

```
(reverse-list '())    ; goes though base case ok, => ()
(reverse-list '(1))   ; => (append (reverse-list '()) (list 1))
(reverse-list '(2 1)) ; => (append (reverse-list '(1)) (list 2))
```

Now in the last example you know `(reverse-list '(1))` is `(1)` so the final would be `(append '(1) '(2))` which gives `(1 2)` which happens to be the reverse. You can continue by adding one more element:

```
(reverse-list '(3 2 1))
; => (append (reverse-list '(2 1)) (list 3))
; => (append '(1 2) '(3))
; ==> (1 2 3)
```